# Forming the orthogonal space is just a special case of forming a polar set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $M\subset X$ be a subspace and define the polar set $M^{\circ}:=\{x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}:|\langle u,x^{\ast}\rangle|\le 1\forall u\in M\}$ and $M^{\perp}:=\{x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}:\langle u,x^{\ast}\rangle =0\forall u\in M\}$

I want to show $M^{\circ}=M^{\perp}$.

The problem is that in every piece of literature I have found, this is stated as a trivial result and so the proof is usually omitted.

But I am essentially trying to show $|\langle u,x^{\ast}\rangle|\le 1\iff\langle u,x^{\ast}\rangle=0$, for all $u\in U$.

i.e. $|x^{\ast}(u)|\le 1\iff x^{\ast}(u)=0$.

And unless I am missing something of the operations of the inner product within the dual space, it seems rather nonsensical (at first glance, at least).

Comment: I think your definition of a polar set is not correct. First I will tell you what might be the problem, and then I tell you the definition which I have read in books. 1) If $U$ has few elements or say $1$ element then you can not prove that from $|x^*(u)|<1,\forall u\in U\Rightarrow x^*(u)=0$. 2) The definition of a polar set that I know is: $U^o:=\{x^*\in X^*: \langle x^*,u\rangle =0\,\forall u\in U\}$

Comment: @Svetoslav Your definition of a polar set is the same as my definition of the orthogonal vector space (which I am trying to prove is equivalent to my definition of the polar set).

Comment: Exactly, this is my point. They are the same. But your's seem not good to me. I will think a little bit more though.

Comment: Aha, I see that you replaced $M$ to be a subspace. Before it was only a set. Now they are the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write only the forward direction. The inverse is trivially true. Assume that $|x^*(u)|=\alpha\in (0,1)$ for some $u\in M$. Because $M$ is a subspace, then $\lambda u\in M$ for each $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. Therefore you must have $|x^*(\lambda u)|=|\lambda|\cdot|x^*(u)|=|\lambda|\cdot\alpha<1$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb R$. But this is impossible, unless $x^*(u)=0,\forall u\in M$

Comment: If $M$ is only a subset of $X$ (not linear subspace), then the two definitions that you give are not equivalent.